# mySQL - Multiple rows into one row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot, multiple-tables

I need data from multiple tables using joins. Below are the tables.

table 1 : list_vehicles

```
pk_vehicle_id   vehicle_reg_no  vehicle_type
1                 REG1              Bus
2                  1                Bus
7                  1                Bus
```

table 2 : list_vehicles

```
pk_route_id     route_code    route_name    route_description
26                CODE1        Route1         First Route
27                CODE2        Route2         Second Route
28                CODE3        Route3         Third Route
```

table 3 : tbl_route_vehicle_mgmt

```
pk_route_veh_id   fk_route_id   fk_vehicle_id
4                    22             2
5                    23             1
6                    27             1
```

table 4: tbl_staff_allocation

```
pk_id   fk_route_id     fk_staff_id    staff_type
 1           27             13          Attendant
 2           27             14          Driver
 3           27             15          Conductor
```

**I need the following data from the above tables, say for pk_route_id =27**

```
Route_Name Vehicle_Number Vehicle_Type Driver_Id    Attendant_Id    Conductor
Route 2         REG1            Bus            13           14             15
```

I tried to write a part of the SQL as follows. I am stuck and not sure how to enhance it to get the required results.

```
SELECT a.route_code,a.route_name,a.route_description, tbl_b.fk_vehicle_id,tbl_c.fk_staff_id,tbl_c.staff_type, tbl_c.fk_route_id
FROM `list_routes` AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_route_vehicle_mgmt AS tbl_b 
    ON a.pk_route_id = tbl_b.fk_route_id
INNER JOIN tbl_staff_allocation AS tbl_c 
    ON a.pk_route_id = tbl_c.fk_route_id

     where a.pk_route_id =27 AND (tbl_c.staff_type ="Driver" OR  tbl_c.staff_type ="Conductot" OR tbl_c.staff_type ="Attendant" )
```

Can anyone please help me with the SQL to get the required data.

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc..) which u r using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use several self join on tbl_staff_allocation

```
SELECT 
      a.route_code
      ,a.route_name
      ,a.route_description
      ,tbl_b.fk_vehicle_id
      ,tbl_c1.fk_route_id
      ,tbl_c1.fk_staff_id as Attendant_id
      ,tbl_c2.fk_staff_id as Driver_id
      ,tbl_c3.fk_staff_id as Conductor_id

FROM `list_routes` AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_route_vehicle_mgmt AS tbl_b  ON a.pk_route_id = tbl_b.fk_route_id
INNER JOIN tbl_staff_allocation AS tbl_c1   ON a.pk_route_id = tbl_c1.fk_route_id and tbl_c1.staff_type ='Attendant'
INNER JOIN tbl_staff_allocation AS tbl_c2   ON a.pk_route_id = tbl_c2.fk_route_id and tbl_c.staff_type ='Driver'
INNER JOIN tbl_staff_allocation AS tbl_c3   ON a.pk_route_id = tbl_c3.fk_route_id and tbl_c.staff_type ='Conductor'
INNER JOIN list_vehicles AS d on d.pk_vehicle_id = tbl_b.fk_vehicle_id
```